# Sum of a valua in a week till a certain day of the week SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my case there is a certain time prescribed for a therapy during a week. The prescribed time for the week is for example 5 hours. And for example in that particular week there were 3 activities of 2 hours, 6 in total. Than I have to note the first activities as 'within prescribed time' and the last is 'over prescribed time'. But how do I calculate the sum of the hours till that last activity of that week, because I have to compare that value to the prescribed hours.

My data looks as follow:

| activity_id | date | yearweek | time | prescribed_time_for_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours |

And this should be the result:

| activity_id | date | yearweek | time | prescribed_time_for_week | Within_prescribed_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours | yes |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours | yes |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01 | 2 hours | 5 hours | no |

This is the query I tried but I get the following error:

*SQL compilation error: error line 49 at position 28 invalid identifier 'A.DATUM'*

Due to  WHERE a.datum <= a2.datum

```
 Select a.activity_id
, a.date
, a.yearweek
, a.time
, a.prescribed_time_for_week
, IFF(a.prescribed_time_for_week > week.total_time, 'yes', 'no') as Within_prescribed_time
from activities as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a2.activity_id
            , a2.yearweek
            , SUM(a2.time) as total_time          
          FROM activities as a2
          WHERE a.date <= a2.date
          GROUP BY a2.activity_id, a2.yearweek) as week
          ON week.activity_id = pt.activity_id
          AND week.yearweek = a.yearweek
```

I hope someone knows how to do this.

Comment: Hi from the message it looks like it is not able to find the column DATUM, please check if this column is present in the table activities, check if it has been defined as a uppercase. If possible please send us the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is enough to use a running **SUM**, my suggestion below.

Example data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1 (
    activity_id INT,
    date DATE,
    yearweek STRING,
    time INT,
    prescribed_time_for_week INT  
);

INSERT INTO T1(activity_id, date, yearweek, time, prescribed_time_for_week)
SELECT *
FROM VALUES 
(1, '2021-01-01', '2021-01', 2, 5),
(2, '2021-01-02', '2021-01', 2, 5),
(3, '2021-01-03', '2021-01', 2, 5) t(activity_id, date, yearweek, time, prescribed_time_for_week);
```

Solution:

```
SELECT a.activity_id, a.date, a.yearweek, a.time, a.prescribed_time_for_week
     , SUM(a.time) OVER(PARTITION BY a.yearweek ORDER BY a.date) AS runing_sum
     , IFF(a.prescribed_time_for_week - SUM(a.time) OVER(PARTITION BY a.yearweek ORDER BY a.date) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS within_prescribed_time
  FROM T1 AS a;
```

Reference: [SUM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum.html)